# How to align Foto using OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv

Need Help, I am trying to align 2 id cards using OpenCV.
If I do it for 2 id cards from the same person then the result works like the picture below

Before Alignment :
[image]

The alignment work perfectly if i tried with the same person id as below picture :

[image]

But if I do for 2 id cards that come from two different person then the result is messy, need help on how to do the alignment in this case

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Read reference image
refFilename = "KTP_Reza_Crop.jpeg"
print("Reading reference image : ", refFilename)
im1 = cv2.imread(refFilename, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
im1 = cv2.cvtColor(im1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

# Read image to be aligned
imFilename = "KTP_Reza_No.jpeg"
print("Reading image to align : ", imFilename)
im2 = cv2.imread(imFilename, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
im2 = cv2.cvtColor(im2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

plt.figure(figsize=[20,10]); 
plt.subplot(121); plt.axis('off'); plt.imshow(im1); plt.title("Original Form")
plt.subplot(122); plt.axis('off'); plt.imshow(im2); plt.title("Testing Form")

# Convert images to grayscale
im1_gray = cv2.cvtColor(im1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
im2_gray = cv2.cvtColor(im2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  

# Detect ORB features and compute descriptors.
MAX_NUM_FEATURES = 500
orb = cv2.ORB_create(MAX_NUM_FEATURES)
keypoints1, descriptors1 = orb.detectAndCompute(im1_gray, None)
keypoints2, descriptors2 = orb.detectAndCompute(im2_gray, None)

# Display 
im1_display = cv2.drawKeypoints(im1, keypoints1, outImage=np.array([]), color=(255, 0, 0), flags=cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)
im2_display = cv2.drawKeypoints(im2, keypoints2, outImage=np.array([]), color=(255, 0, 0), flags=cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)

plt.figure(figsize=[20,10])
plt.subplot(121); plt.axis('off'); plt.imshow(im1_display); plt.title("Original Form");
plt.subplot(122); plt.axis('off'); plt.imshow(im2_display); plt.title("Testing Form");

# Match features.
matcher = cv2.DescriptorMatcher_create(cv2.DESCRIPTOR_MATCHER_BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING)
matches = matcher.match(descriptors1, descriptors2, None)
  
# Sort matches by score
matches = sorted(matches, key = lambda x:x.distance)

# Remove not so good matches
numGoodMatches = int(len(matches) * 0.1)
matches = matches[:numGoodMatches]

# Draw top matches
im_matches = cv2.drawMatches(im1, keypoints1, im2, keypoints2, matches, None)

plt.figure(figsize=[40,10])
plt.imshow(im_matches); plt.axis('off'); plt.title("Original Form");


# Extract location of good matches
points1 = np.zeros((len(matches), 2), dtype=np.float32)
points2 = np.zeros((len(matches), 2), dtype=np.float32)

for i, match in enumerate(matches):
  points1[i, :] = keypoints1[match.queryIdx].pt
  points2[i, :] = keypoints2[match.trainIdx].pt
  
# Find homography
h, mask = cv2.findHomography(points2, points1, cv2.RANSAC)

# Use homography to warp image
height, width, channels = im1.shape
im2_reg = cv2.warpPerspective(im2, h, (width, height))
# Display results 
plt.figure(figsize=[20,10]); 
plt.subplot(121); plt.imshow(im1); plt.axis('off'); plt.title("Original Form");
plt.subplot(122); plt.imshow(im2_reg); plt.axis('off'); plt.title("Testing Form");
```

Comment: Using ORB features may be the reason why jt cannot find a good match. Try using SURF or SIFT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two id cards with different persons may not be working well because in such a case, the two images will be similar but not exactly same, for eg: name will be different and photo would be different etc., hence the key points and descriptors would be different for both the images & your output is getting affected.

You can detect the outer edge of the id card by using edge detection and selecting the largest contour and then use [perspective transform](https://pyimagesearch.com/2014/08/25/4-point-opencv-getperspective-transform-example/) to get a top down view if that's what you are aiming for.